# How to get product id from invoice?

Tags: product, invoice

I have order and invoice. I want to get product from invoice and I tried 2 function **`getAllItems()`** and **`getItemsCollection()`** but not found product_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get product id from order # using following code:

```
<?php $orderIncrementId = '100000010';
       $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
       $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
       foreach($items as $i):
          echo $i->getProductId();
       endforeach;

    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just found solution but your help is very useful! :)

Comment: Hey i am have an issue similar, how to get product id from payment? Can u help me again, sir?

Comment: Oh sr solution is smilar. Tks u again. :v